# Custom view in toolbar under the title

Tags: android, android-layout, toolbar, android-custom-view

I know (and use it) how to add a custom view to a Toolbar (as ActionBar).  However my requirement now is to display that custom view *below* the title.  Is there a way to achieve this without having to also include the title into that custom view?  I prefer to leave the title management to the toolbar itself.

Comment: You need to Create a BaseActivity with toolbar.

Comment: have you got any solution

Comment: @user987362 No, I haven't - I included the title in the custom view instead.

Answer (score -1):

I understand the wrong thing !

You can try

```
View custom  = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom,toolbar,true);

custom.setLayoutParams();
```

I'm going to bed.

Comment: I don't think I follow your logic.  What is `R.layout.toolbar` and what is `R.layout.base`? and what is `R.layout.sub`?

Comment: I update R.layout.base .Toolbar is in R.layout.base and In subActivity you put in a layoutid

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand.  What is a subID?  Also I don't see any code that sets the custom view into the toolbar at all, not to mention sets the correct layout of it.

Comment: R.layout.sub is your custom view.

Comment: Ok, now I see what you are doing - and it's totally not what I was asking.  You are simply creating a layout just below the toolbar.  I need to have the custom view be _part of_ of the toolbar itself.

Answer (score -1):

you also can use the appbar ,

```
<AppBarLayout>
  <Toolbar/>
  <CustonView/>
<AppBarLayout/>
```

check the official documentation 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html